# Can you compute optimal shapes?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Disclaimer: Someone may have already asked this, but I couldn’t find it.

Given a positive integer n and an arbitrary minimum distance between each can you reasonably compute the optimal arrangement for n points such that the collective distance between all of the points is minimized? If you can do it in a 2d plane, how about 3d? Would you have to do it separately for each n or is there some similarity between all such problems that allows you to work off of previous data? Is the computational complexity too high? Thank you.

Edit: To clarify, by collective distance I mean the sum of the distances of all connections, ex:
If n =4,then the collective distance is
AB + AC + AD + BC + BD + CD.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). If so, there is no explicit formula for it; see the section on **Computation** in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Théophile This sounds more like [circle-packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) and sphere-packing to me. It depends on what is meant by "collective distance" of course. And if this aribtrary minimum distance is not the same for all point pairs, then it isn't necessarily the same as packing circles.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes, you're probably right. The wording needs to be clarified: "Given a set of $n$ points" implies that these points are already fixed, and we need to find some additional position (the geometric median?) in relation to them. But perhaps the problem is really "Given a positive integer $n$, arrange $n$ points such that $\ldots$", which would indeed be sphere-packing.